# SiteTreeExtension->augmentSQL seems to cause empty fields

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm developing a simple module to provide 'soft' scheduling of pages (Embargo & Expire, I'm aware this is also provided by the workflow module). For this I wrote a SiteTreeExtension which adds Embargo & Expiry as Datetimefields.

I'm trying to implement augmentSQL on this in order to filter out pages that are under embargo/expiry. But any time I add an extra 'Where' clause to the augmentSQL method involving the Embargo or Expiry fields, the 'Embargo' and 'Expiry' fields of all resulting Pages appear unset. If I comment out the 'addWhere' lines, these fields load their data just fine.

How can I add a correct where clause so pages under embargo/expiry will be excluded?

```
class EmbargoExpirySchedulerExtension extends SiteTreeExtension { 

   public static $db = array( 
      'Embargo' => 'SS_Datetime', 
      'Expiry' => 'SS_Datetime' 
   );

   ...

   function augmentSQL(SQLQuery &$query) { 
      $myclass = $this->owner->className; 
      if (is_subclass_of(Controller::curr(), 'ContentController')) { // on frontend 
         $query 
            ->addWhere(array(
               // ( These lines seem to cause Embargo/Expiry to be unset/empty: )   
               "\"{$myclass}\".\"Embargo\" IS NULL OR \"{$myclass}\".\"Embargo\" < NOW()", 
               "\"{$myclass}\".\"Expiry\" IS NULL OR \"{$myclass}\".\"Expiry\" > NOW()", 
            )); 
      } 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying this extension to `SiteTree` then your `Embargo` and `Expiry` fields will be added to the `SiteTree` table.

You are calling `{$myclass}.Embargo` and `{$myclass}.Expiry`.

If you are on a page of type `HomePage` this will query `HomePage.Embargo` and `HomePage.Expiry`.

`Embargo` and `Expiry` do not exist on the `HomePage` table. They exist on the `SiteTree` table.

Instead you want to query `SiteTree.Embargo` and `SiteTree.Expiry`.

Also, in your query for tables and columns rather than using escaped double quote `\"`  use back ticks `` ` `` instead:

```
->addWhere(array( 
    "`SiteTree`.`Embargo` IS NULL OR `SiteTree`.`Embargo` < NOW()", 
    "`SiteTree`.`Expiry` IS NULL OR `SiteTree`.`Expiry` > NOW()"
));
```

Back ticks make the code neater and will append `_Live` or `_versions` automatically when necessary.

Comment: Double quotes are used to support postgreSQL, although probably not important here.